# Why can't I assign to a variable being referenced in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$bar = 7;
$foo =& $bar = 9;
```

From a technical stand point, wouldn't this be evaluated from right to left?
So: $bar = 9; $foo =& $bar

In case anyone is wondering. The reason I'm doing this on one line is to avoid toe nail clippings.

Comment: Toe nail clippings?

Comment: It's the same as `$foo =& ($bar = 9)`, which obviously does not work.

Comment: Adding brackets does not make things any more obvious in this case. Mind you I'm simply being devil's advocate. Although I'm not a fan that semantically 9 is returned $bar, this makes sense.

Comment: Tim: I call brackets toe nail clippings. I heard it from someone else when they were describing lisp. Generally, I try to avoid brackets if I can, because they either cause more vertical spacing than necessary, or arbitrarily exist somewhere on the right hand side of the beginning or end of a statement.
They serve a purpose in many cases, but sometimes they are unnecessary; even for formatting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The assignment expression `$bar = 9` doesn't return a reference to `$bar` (i.e. the variable itself); instead, it returns the integer value `9`.

Or if you need a quote from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

> The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned. That is, the value of "*$a = 3*" is 3.

You can't assign a reference directly to a value, only to a variable that holds that value. So your handy one-liner fails spectacularly, and you'll have to split it into two.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock, this makes sense.
Does it work this way in C++? I don't have a compiler handy.
If it doesn't work that way in C++, is there any language that would work this way? Is it even possible?

I mean, why not return $bar and wait till the last possible second to evaluate bar to a literal, this way you can get the reference of bar, rather than be stuck with the literal?

Comment: As far as I know, it behaves the same in other C-style languages for primitives (ints, longs, floats, chars) - assignment expressions always basically return the value being assigned. As for your last question... I'm not sure about the exact semantics of assignment operators, so I can't elaborate on that.

Comment: haha, thinking about it, my mind is a little spoiled from so much javascript. The problem is that $bar and all variables are not references.

So Bolt, would the following C++ work:
    "int v; int& j; v = j = 9;"
I think it would. Alas, I don't think you can write anything similar in PHP.

Comment: Ah, I just checked that in C++ you can change the order of assignment using brackets [ie. (a = b) = c; ], unfortunately it is not valid to add brackets in an assignment in PHP [ie. ($a &= $b) = $c; ]. This is another mystery to me. This is beyond the scope of this question, however.

Answer (score 2):

For the very same reason that

```
$bar =& 9;
```

is not valid (because reference can point to another variable, but not constant / literal). See :
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: See BoltClock's answer for what I was confused about. I know you can't take a reference from a literal. What I didn't know was that assignment returned a literal rather than a reference.